# how to map items between two array through dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

i have two arrays including shipment and sales .
we need to get shipment items and cancel items base on these two arrays.
for example
shipment arrays , the product 0A6910XL and 01100M was separated shipped 1 pcs.
but the externalItemNumber of 01100M is empty.

```
[
    {
        "sku": "0A6910XL",
        "giQty": "1.000",
        "pickedQty": "1.000",
        "requiredQty": 0,
        "externalItemNumber": "14303087"
    },
    {
        "sku": "01100M",
        "giQty": "1.000",
        "pickedQty": "1.000",
        "requiredQty": 0,
        "externalItemNumber": ""
    }   
]
```

base on sales order number, we can get the corresponding sales order items
like below, we can know the product 01100M be ordered 2 pcs.

```
[
    {
        "sku": "06910XL",
        "quantity": 1,
        "orderItemId": "14303087"
    },
    {
        "sku": "01100M",
        "quantity": 1,
        "orderItemId": "14303088"
    },
    {
        "sku": "01100M",
        "quantity": 1,
        "orderItemId": "14303089"
    }
]
```

now, we need to get two arrays , shipment and cancellation.  Notes the "01100M" was ordered 2 pcs, but only be shipped 1 pcs.
my expected results is below
shipment,  we need to get any orderItemId from original sales order to input externalItemNumber  .
expected output of shipment

```
[
    {
        "sku": "0A6910XL",
        "giQty": "1.000",
        "pickedQty": "1.000",
        "requiredQty": 0,
        "externalItemNumber": "14303087"
    },
    {
        "sku": "01100M",
        "giQty": "1.000",
        "pickedQty": "1.000",
        "requiredQty": 0,
        "externalItemNumber": "14303088"
    }   
]
```

expected output of cancellation items

```
[

    {
        "sku": "01100M",
        "giQty": "1.000",
        "pickedQty": "1.000",
        "requiredQty": 0,
        "externalItemNumber": "14303089"
    }   
]
```

i can get result through "for each" , but i'd like to know if we can
get result through dataweave transformation.

thanks

Comment: Please clarify in your question which are the inputs, and which the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [join](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-join)() or one of its variants from the [Arrays](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays) module to join the Arrays, then map as needed.

You can find examples by searching previous `join` answers here with tag `[dataweave]`: `[dataweave] join`.

Comment: the join variants should be sku ++ externalItemNumber(orderItemId), but the question is that externalItemNumber of some items in the shipment array is empty .

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify it.